# Is it time to get rid of the [real-world]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I recently discovered that we have a [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world) tag.

Firstly, I'm **really not sure when this tag is meant to be used**. It can't be for *all* out-of-universe questions, as it would then have a lot more than 35 questions to its name. The tag wiki doesn't give much help or clear guidance:

> This tag usually refers to how something in Sci-Fi or Fantasy works in the real world. It can also refer to a version of our world featured in a Sci-Fi or Fantasy work. For instance, Stephen King uses a version of himself in what is supposedly our world in his Dark Tower novels.

Secondly, we have a policy (and even a custom close-vote reason) that **questions asking about real-world science are off-topic** unless somehow linked to a particular work of SF/F. This policy is still unclear, however, and having a tag that seems to apply to such questions is only going to exacerbate the problem.

### Can we nuke this tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Nuke it

1. Does it make sense to be an "expert" in [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world)?
   **No (-1)**
2. Does it make sense for a question to be tagged *only* with [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world)?
   **No (-1)** — it's a meta tag.
3. Does [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world) have a single, universally-unambiguous meaning?
   **Maybe (1)**
4. Is [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world) likely to be used correctly just based on its name?
   **Maybe (1)**
5. Are there "enough" (> 15) but not "too many" (> 10% site-wide) questions that qualify for [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world)?
   **Yes (2)** — currently 35 and could be used on more.
6. Are people likely to use [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world) to find questions to answer?
   **No (-1)** — not by itself, *perhaps* in conjunction with another tag, but even that is unlikely.
7. Are there likely some users (*be objective!*) who will favorite or ignore [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world)?
   **Yes (2)** — the tag currently exists and has 2 followers.
8. Could [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world) be reasonably used to feed questions to a specialized chat room?
   **No (-1)**
9. Can [real-world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world) be used to search for questions (for any reason) in a way that keyword searching cannot accomplish?
   **Maybe (1)**

Total is **3**, which is low enough to get rid of this tag.

Comment: Though I agree with your conclusion, perhaps the answers to #3 and #4 should be **no** (as discussed in my question) and the answer to #6 should be **maybe** (a real-world scientist might indeed look for [tag:real-world] questions to answer). On a more general note, IMO the facts that the tag has **unclear usage guidance** and **its most obvious usage is *off-topic*** are more important than several of the questions in this list, which after all was originally designed for a different site and hasn't been changed at all for SFF. I'm beginning to agree with CreationEdge about these criteria ...

Comment: I've weeded out all the questions in this tag that are about real-world *explanations*, and all the remaining questions would fit just as well with the [tag:influences] / [tag:inspiration] tag. In a day or two (giving people time to object) I'll get rid of [tag:real-world] by merging all three of these tags together - thus, in a way, satisfying both your answer and CreationEdge's :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say no, but that it just needs to be renamed to [real-world-influence](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-world-influence)

Expert? Yes. +2

Tagged only? No. -1

Unambiguous? Yes. +2

Used correctly based on name? Yes +2.

Enough? Yes. +2

Use it to find questions? Maybe, but leaning to no. -1

Favorite or ignore? Maybe +1

Specialized chat? No. -1

Search? Yes (people use "influence", "origin", "idea of", etc., in questions.) +2

Total: **8**

An okay tag, but not terrible.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by [tag:real-world-influence]. Would that be used for questions about what (in the real world) *influenced* this or that in a work of SF/F? We have the [tag:inspiration] tag for that. If you look at how the [tag:real-world] tag is used, it's often on questions about whether such-and-such would actually work in the real world. (Although now that I look at it, you're right that some of those questions are actually about real-world inspiration instead. Some serious retagging needed here.)

Comment: Retagging, or a synonym. Someone tried using influence recently, and it'd make a decent synonym, if not already explicitly worded in the wiki. Can't see it atm.

Comment: @randal'thor Although, I agree that if it's used to ask for real-world *explanations*, it seems redundant and pointless. Just like tagging plot-explanation.

Comment: I just realised we already have two tags for the thing you're talking about: see [this new meta post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9226/synonymise-influences-and-inspiration-tags). Would you agree on nuking the [tag:real-world] tag, retagging some of those questions with [tag:influences], and simply removing the tag from the questions about real-world explanations?

Comment: @rand I think having it for real world explanations is overkill, yes. But for retagging, isn't it possible to rename a tag (as a mod?) and then just make it a synonym. Less work, and less disruptive, if possible.

Comment: Yes, that's possible for a mod to do, but before merging the tag into [tag:influences] we'd have to untag all the [tag:real-world] questions which are about real-world *explanations* and not influences.

Comment: I've weeded out the real-world explanation questions, and everything that still has the [tag:real-world] tag would fit with [tag:influences]. In a day or two (giving people time to object) I'll merge all three of [tag:real-world], [tag:influences], and [tag:inspiration] together - thus, in a way, satisfying both your answer and SQB's :-)